# Using swap! on a nested map

Tags: clojure

I'm following Chapter 6 of the book Professional Clojure.

App state is currently defined as follows:

```clj
(defonce app-state                                          
  (reagent/atom
    {:projects
     {"aaa"
      {:title "Build Whip"
       :stories
       {1 {:title "Design a data model for projects and stories"    
           :status "done"                                           
           :order 1}                                                
        2 {:title "Create a story title entry form"                 
           :order 2}    
        3 {:title "Implement a way to finish stories"
           :order 3}}}}}))
```

I need to use `swap!` to add a new key value to represent a new story, keyed by an id with value of the given fields.

```clj
(defn add-story! [app-state project-id title status]     ;
  ; Q. How to use swap! to add a key value pair into :stories?
  (swap! app-state update [:projects project-id :stories] assoc      <- INCORRECT CODE HERE
         (unique) {:title title
                   :status status
                   :order (inc (max-order app-state project-id))}))
```

The unique function not shown here just generates any unique uuid.
The max-order function gets, well, the max order.
I had to modify it as the book chapter proceeds inconsistently with the actual final code supplied. Here's my version of max-order:

```clj
(defn max-order [app-state project-id]
  (apply max 0 (map :order (vals (get-in @app-state [:projects project-id :stories])))))
```

**Question**: How can I use `swap!` to add a new key value into `:stories`?

I had a go at it but it beat me for now.

I do get the feeling this nested map is not the best representation - in the final code supplied as a download the author has changed to a more relational-type model with projects and stories both as top level entities, with stories containing a project_id, but would be nice to solve this first use of `swap!` before moving on to that.

Comment: there is a typo and `update` should actually be `update-in`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just use `assoc-in` in this case which is a bit simpler than `update-in` and better describes what you're trying to achieve:

```
(def app-state
  (atom 
   {:projects
    {"aaa"
     {:title   "Build Whip"
      :stories {1 {:title  "Design a data model for projects and stories"
                   :status "done"
                   :order  1}
                2 {:title "Create a story title entry form"
                   :order 2}
                3 {:title "Implement a way to finish stories"
                   :order 3}}}}}))

(defn unique [] (rand-int 1000000000))

(let [unique-key (unique)]
  (swap! app-state
         assoc-in
         [:projects "aaa" :stories unique-key]
         {:title  (str "Agent " unique-key)
          :status "foxy"
          :order  "some-order-stuff"}))
@app-state
;; => {:projects
;;     {"aaa"
;;      {:title "Build Whip",
;;       :stories
;;       {1 {:title "Design a data model for projects and stories", :status "done", :order 1},
;;        2 {:title "Create a story title entry form", :order 2},
;;        3 {:title "Implement a way to finish stories", :order 3},
;;        295226401 {:title "Agent 295226401", :status "foxy", :order "some-order-stuff"}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to study the [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) daily!  Also, more [documentation references here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

I think you just need to use `update-in`

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    ))

(def state
  {:projects
   {"aaa"
    {:title   "Build Whip"
     :stories {1 {:title  "Design a data model for projects and stories"
                  :status "done"
                  :order  1}
               2 {:title "Create a story title entry form"
                  :order 2}
               3 {:title "Implement a way to finish stories"
                  :order 3}}}}})

(dotest
  (let [result (update-in state [:projects "aaa" :stories]
                 assoc 99 {:title  "Agent 99"
                           :status "foxy"
                           :order  "some-order-stuff"})
        ]
    (spyx-pretty result)))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
result => 
{:projects
 {"aaa"
  {:title "Build Whip",
   :stories
   {1
    {:title "Design a data model for projects and stories",
     :status "done",
     :order 1},
    2   {:title "Create a story title entry form", :order 2},
    3   {:title "Implement a way to finish stories", :order 3},
    99  {:title "Agent 99", :status "foxy", :order "some-order-stuff"}}}}}
```

When the data is inside an atom, the solution is nearly the same:

```
  (def state-atom (atom state))
  (let [result (swap! state-atom update-in [:projects "aaa" :stories]
                 assoc 99 {:title  "Agent 99"
                           :status "foxy"
                           :order  "some-order-stuff"})]
    (spyx-pretty @state-atom))
```

with result

```
(clojure.core/deref state-atom) => 
{:projects
 {"aaa"
  {:title "Build Whip",
   :stories
   {1
    {:title "Design a data model for projects and stories",
     :status "done",
     :order 1},
    2 {:title "Create a story title entry form", :order 2},
    3 {:title "Implement a way to finish stories", :order 3},
    99
    {:title "Agent 99", :status "foxy", :order "some-order-stuff"}}}}}
```